# Why is there less oxygen in a pressurised plane that is flying?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, everyday-life, atmospheric-science, gas

Children who have temporary lung problems like asthma attacks have to go on oxygen to heal. (At a hospital.) Immediately after a health incident they can’t go on an aeroplane because there is insufficient oxygen levels. (According to Doctors advice.)

I’m trying to figure this out. Surely if you have a sealed tube of air and you raise it to 1000 metres, the quantity of oxygen doesn’t change.

Even if you account for people breathing, then surely the scrubbers put it back?

Is there a law of physics acting in this situation I’m not aware of?

My question is: **Why is there less oxygen in a pressurised plane that is flying?**

Comment: Why do you believe a plane is a "sealed tube of air"?

Comment: As a starting point for the reasoning about whether gravity affects oxygen concentrations at higher altitudes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google says "Although aircraft cabins are pressurized, cabin air pressure at cruising altitude is lower than air pressure at sea level. At typical cruising altitudes in the range 11 000–12 200 m (36 000–40 000 feet), air pressure in the cabin is equivalent to the outside air pressure at 1800–2400 m (6000–8000 feet) above sea level."   That means there is significantly less oxygen in-flight.  About 20-30% based on the barometric pressure.  This is a cost saving for the airlines.

Answer (score 0):

because an airplane is pressurized typically to an altitude of about 10,000 feet or perhaps a bit less- NOT to full sea-level pressure. 10,000 feet is the maximum altitude a pilot can withstand for a long flight without progressive cognitive impairment. Healthy people can take 10,000 feet without ill effects but not people with pulmonary problems.

Comment: Thanks - can you give me a name for this concept or research so I can go look it up?

Comment: I live at nearly 2000m above sea level.  I can tell you that no two people will react the same way to altitude.  I've seen healthy people with severe altitude headaches well below 10,000 feet.   In fact, I know one person who got headaches just flying into Denver.  Some people need days to acclimate, and some are ready to race just off the plane.  If I drive up Mt. Evans (about 4000m) I get dizzy, but I can ride my bike up with no problem; just those few hours is enough to acclimate.

Comment: the name of this effect is the decrease of partial pressure of oxygen with altitude  and lots has been written about it. the essentials are: as you go up in altitude, the atmospheric pressure decreases, which means the air gets less dense- and a cubic meter of it therefore contains less oxygen. above 10,000 feet, pilots must breathe oxygen in order to stay alert and awake in a percentage that scales with altitude; by 20,000 feet this percentage goes to 100% and above that the pilot exhibits impairment even on 100% O2.

Answer (score 0):

Other people answered that air pressure inside airplanes is less than the atmospheric pressure at sea level. However, you asked "Is there a law of physics acting in this situation I’m not aware of?" As far as I know, this is done because otherwise airplanes would need to be designed for higher pressure difference between interior and exterior of the plane, which would typically require increase of the mass of the airplane.